# Mocking boolean __bool__ protocol method in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-requests

As part of my unittests, I am testing some responses using the fantastic Requests library. Something cool you can do with this library is test a response for a `200` OK status code by simply calling:

```py
r = requests.get("http://example.com")
if r:
    # success code, do something...
else:
    # error code, handle the error.
```

The way this works behind the scenes is Requests updates the `__bool__()` protocol method of the response returned according to the type of status code.

What I'd like to do is to be able to mock the response object of `requests.get()` well enough so that I can not only patch the methods/attributes I'm interested in checking (`status_code`, `json()`) but also to be able to return `False` whenever I choose to.

The following isn't working for me, as once I call `r` from the sample code above, it returns the Mock object `<Mock id='2998569132'>` which evaluates to `True`.

```py
with mock.patch.object(requests, 'get', return_value=mock.MagicMock(
    # False, # didn't work
    # __bool__=mock.Mock(return_value=False), # throws AttributeError, might be Python2.7 problem
    # ok=False, # works if I call if r.ok: instead, but it's not what I want
    status_code=401,
    json=mock.Mock(
    return_value={
        u'error': {
            u'code': 401,
            u'message':
            u'Request had invalid authentication credentials.',
            u'status': u'UNAUTHENTICATED'
        }
    }
)
)) as mock_account_get_failure:
# mock_account_get_failure.return_value = False # overwrites what I just mocked with json() and status_code
```

I thought the answer might lie in [Magic Mocking the protocol method's return value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#magic-mock), but read [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/magicmock.html) that `__bool__` is only supported for Python 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

In python2.7, you should mock `__nonzero__` instead of `__bool__`.

`m = mock.MagicMock(__nonzero__=mock.Mock(return_value=False), status_code=400)
m.status_code  # > 400
bool(m)        # > False`